# Why isn't Outlook letting me remove an email account that's not the primary?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

[image]

Assume after I click on the Outlook icon, 1 (with checkmark) is the first email account that appears on screen. I'm using Outlook 19.

I want to remove just 2 (the one at bottom). Why did this pop-up appear? I'm unmistakably NOT removing the "primary account".

Comment: `I'm unmistakably NOT removing the "primary account"???` - why do you think so? The first account in the screenshot is marked as primary account. Select one of the others, "set as default", then you'll be able to remove the first one.

Comment: In the screenshot, it looks like 3 is selected, when it should be 1 which is selected. Are you saying that you clicked on 1, clicked "Remove", and then it changed the selection to 3?

Comment: @AndrewMOrton This screenshot isn't mine. But I clicked on 3, and the same pop-up appeared.

Comment: @AndrewMOrton I changed the screenshot. The original wasn't mind, but now the screenshot is.

Comment: #2 is the primary exchange account for the 2 nested exchange accounts under it... those exchange accounts must be removed to remove their parent, #2.  This is how it appears from your screenshot, but if not, please re-take the screenshot with the error box below _all_ the accounts, not just the first two